# Как сделать строку подключения динамической, чтобы при изменении расположения папки с программой, программа не выдавала ошибку

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, windows, datagridview

Сейчас строка подключения такая

```
string ConnStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Админ\\Desktop\\Проекты\\.net C# Windows form\\Dictonary\\Dictonary\\BD\\MyDataBase.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: [AppDomain.BaseDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_AppDomain_BaseDirectory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.StartupPath + "\\папка в которой лежит база (если есть папка)\\MyDataBase.mdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

создать папку в рядом с .ехе файлом и заменить название **Название вашей Папки** на ваше и поместить в папку файл **MyDataBase.mdf**

```
  string ConnStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"Название вашей Папки\\MyDataBase.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file BD\MyDataBase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Comment: попробуйте `\\BD\\MyDataBase.mdf` она должна лежать там где .ехе  если это Debug то папка ваш проект `\bin\Debug\BD\MyDataBase.mdf если Release то bin\Release\\BD\MyDataBase.mdf

Comment: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file \BD\MyDataBase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Comment: Обратите внимание на комментарий выше `AppDomain.BaseDirectory – XelaNimed 13 часов назад`